# Build Commands Failed Error Code 65 Ionic (iOS)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification

I'm using ionic to build my iOS app but im having this problem when running the command : "ionic build ios"

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/HR\ APP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HR\ APP.build/Objects-normal/i386/PushPlugin.o HR\ APP/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin/PushPlugin.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/user/desktop/hr/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,HR APP.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,HR APP,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/user/desktop/hr/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/user/desktop/hr/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Comment: same here.. will look into it more now. Did you use the google maps native wrapper for Phonegap by any chance?

Comment: @Pascal No , but using 'ionic platform add ios@3.9.2 helps me fix this issue. Temporary fix though

Answer (score 1):

Try This command

```
phonegap plugin remove phonegap-plugin-push
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue,
I would like to let you know my machine local environment setup-

```
******************************************************
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68
******************************************************
```

It generally occurs when we took app raw code form some other machine and try to build.
When I search for that I came to know that this issue is taking place due of ***spaces from build path***
Steps I followed-

1. Opened app config.xml in editor.
2. Renamed App name such as-

---

```
<name>Rername App Title</name>
```

3. `$ cordova plugin save`
4. `$ cordova platform rm ios`
5. `$ cordova platform add ios`
   After this I just build the app

---

```
$ ionic build ios
```

And that worked for me, hope you will get your issue resolved too.
This link helped me a lot-
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-build-ios-fails-android-works/10515/2

*Note:- Make sure you have complete [icon and splash of the app for each platform](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html) i.e-*

```
ionic resources
```