# Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig?

Tags: ios, cordova

this error on cordova run ios --device.
if  i run my app through xcode then it goes right but when i use CLI it stuck with above error.

Answer (score 0):

This is [similar to this answer of mine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561511/build-commands-failed-error-code-65-ionic-ios/41976804#41976804)
**I had this same issue but in ionic and ionic also use phone-gap so I this this will help you too.**
I would like to let you know my machine local environment setup-

```
******************************************************
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68
******************************************************
```

It generally occurs when we took app raw code form some other machine and try to build.
When I search for that I came to know that this issue is taking place due of ***spaces from build path***
Steps I followed-

1. Opened app config.xml in editor.
2. Renamed App name such as-

---

```
<name>Rername App Title</name>
```

3. `$ cordova plugin save`
4. `$ cordova platform rm ios`
5. `$ cordova platform add ios`
   After this I just build the app

---

```
$ ionic build ios
```

And that worked for me, hope you will get your issue resolved too.
This link helped me a lot-
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-build-ios-fails-android-works/10515/2

*Note:- Make sure you have complete [icon and splash of the app for each platform](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html) i.e-*

```
ionic resources
```